Error deploying MERN stack app to Vercel/Render: Cannot find module './mongodb_oidc/azure_machine_workflow'
I'm currently developing an application using the MERN stack, and I'm in the process of deploying it. Everything works well locally. However, when I try to deploy it to Vercel or Render, I encounter the following error:
Cannot find module './mongodb_oidc/azure_machine_workflow' Require stack:

/var/task/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/auth/mongodb_oidc.js

/var/task/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client_auth_providers.js

/var/task/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js

/var/task/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js

/var/task/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js Did you forget to add it to "dependencies" in package.json? Node.js process exited with exit status: 1. The logs above can help with debugging the issue. INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 690.68 ms Phase: invoke Status: error Error Type: Runtime.ExitError 


This is my package.json
{
  "name": "musicback",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "mongodb": "^6.7.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.4.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.2"
  }
}

I have tried the following solutions:Installed all dependencies again. Updated all npm packages. Cleared the node cache. Despite these efforts, the error persists. As a new developer in full-stack development, I have not deployed an application before and couldn't find any information about this specific error online.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
